# Chez Scheme: Macroexpand implementation

Tags: scheme, chez-scheme

Does Chez Scheme offer a standard `macroexpand` implementation? If not, does some suitable replacement exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by standard? There's `expand` which expands a form supplied to it.

Comment: `expand` appears to expand all levels of macros - it's so detailed that it even expands `cond` into `if`. Is there something that expands only one level of macros?

Comment: they are looking for something like Clojure's [macroexpand-1](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand-1).

Comment: One can call the syntax transformers directly.  Nothing is needed outside the R6RS standard.